# RDLC QRCode Print

Tags: asp.net, .net, printing, rdlc, qr-code

I wanna ask something about print `QRCode` in `RDLC`.
First, I Store the image text in database.
and when I want to print, I just call it.

Example :

[image]

but the problem is, how I can print it like this:

[image]

- **After 13 QR Images to the right, Go to the next row**
- **After 12 Rows, Go To The Next Page**

AND Each QRCode have different Unique ID.
but when try it before i post this question. all images have same ID.
and other problems is, when i try to grouping, after 13 QRImages, it doesn't go to next row. but do a page break.

=========================================================================

**EDIT**

This question is solved by myself.
Thanks.

Comment: I think the best solution is set Columns and ColumnSpacing properties of your report, put a List inside Column1 and an Image inside this List. This solution has a big problem: your QR will be displayed filling every row in Column1, then every row in Column2 and so on.

Comment: Thanks For Reply My Problem.. actually, this problem has been solved. i created pivot in sql way, then make rdlc report as usual.